# Google App Engine : import myfile gives 502 bad gateway

Tags: google-app-engine

App runs fine with just the app.yaml, main.py and requiremets.txt (Flask)

I also have a mymodule.py file.

If, in main.py, I do

```
import mymodule
```

or

```
from mymodule import myfunc
```

I get the 502 Bad Gateway

runs fine locally though..

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the official documentation on :

[Specifying Private Dependencies](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/specifying-dependencies)

> To use private dependencies:
>
> 1.Run `pip install -t lib my_module` to copy dependencies into a local
> folder named `lib`.
>
> 2.Add an empty `__init__.py`  file to the `lib` directory to make it a
> module.
>
> 3.Import the module in your app. For example:
>
> `import lib.my_module`